# How to retrieve the notify icon balloon tip title?

Tags: c#, winapi

How do I retrieve the notify icon balloon tip title? I can get the balloon tip text like this:

```c
SendMessage(hWnd1_tooltip, WM_GETTEXT, buffer_size, strTitle);
```

but I cannot get the notify icon balloon tip title.

Comment: Don't use tags whose description starts with "DO NOT USE".

Comment: Please post the minimal working example so that it can be seen how you create those notification balloons and how you attempt to get its contents.

Comment: See [`TTM_GETTITLE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760396.aspx): "*Retrieve information concerning the title of a tooltip control.*"

Answer (score 1):

Send the tooltip control a [`TTM_GETTITLE` message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760396.aspx):

```
TTGETTITLE ttgt;
ttgt.dwSize = sizeof(ttgt);
SendMessage(hwndTooltip, TTM_GETTITLE, 0, (LPARAM)ttgt);

MessageBox(NULL, ttgt.pszTitle, TEXT("Demo"), MB_OK);
```

You tagged this question [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), but the code you've written sure looks like C. If the question is simply mistagged, the above code shows what you would do in C or C++.

If you're actually using C#, you shouldn't have any need to do this at all. You should just use the [`ToolTipTitle` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.tooltiptitle.aspx) provided by the ToolTip wrapper class (if you're using WinForms), or whatever the equivalent is for WPF.

But here are the required P/Invoke declarations:

```
internal class NativeMethods
{
   const UInt32 WM_USER = 0x0400;
   const UInt32 TTM_GETTITLE = (WM_USER + 35);

   [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
   struct TTGETTITLE
   {
      public UInt32 dwSize;
      public UInt32 uTitleBitmap;
      public UInt32 cch;
      public IntPtr pszTitle;
   }

   [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
   static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, ref TTGETTITLE lParam);
}
```

Which you can use like this:

```
public string GetTooltipTitle(IntPtr hwndTooltip)
{
      TTGETTITLE ttgt = new TTGETTITLE();
      ttgt.dwSize = (UInt32)Marshal.SizeOf(ttgt);
      SendMessage(hwndTooltip, TTM_GETTITLE, IntPtr.Zero, ref ttgt);
      return Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(ttgt.pszTitle);
}
```

Again, I'm not really sure where you're going to be getting a window handle for a tooltip control when you're writing this in C#. If your goal is to retrieve the title of a tooltip displayed by a *different process*, you're going to have a hard time. The common controls library doesn't marshal strings across processes.

Comment: thank you very much,my coded is written by c#,and can you give me all your code?
this isn't work:
StringBuilder strTitle = new StringBuilder(length);
const int buffer_size = 1024;
SendMessage(hWnd1_tooltip, TTM_GETTITLE, buffer_size, strTitle);
MessageBox.Show(strTitle.ToString());
the strTitle is null

Comment: I don't have any code. I wrote this directly into the answer box. I'll try to edit in a C# version.

Comment: thank you very much ,i worked hard this for about 5 days...and i've searched almost everywhere ,but i can't get the right code or right answer ,thank you for replied this.

Comment: my  goal is to retrieve the title of a tooltip displayed by a different process, and  excuse me , do you  any  other solution?thank you very much,i will go on.

Comment: @hip It will probably work cross-process, but you must allocate global memory for the `TTGETTITLE` so that it can be accessed from another process. (One process cannot read another process's memory, so when you pass the pointer to a locally-allocated `TTGETTITLE`, it won't be able to fill it.) Making a globally readable allocation will entail the use of `Marshal.AllocHGlobal`. You'll then pass that pointer, and later free with `Marshal.FreeHGlobal`. I don't feel like writing yet another answer. All of these details you've provided in comments should have been included in the original question.